# Determining Key with Most Values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dictionary = {"key1": ["Item1", "Item2"], "key2": ["Item3", "Item4"]}
```

Working with the above dictionary, trying to iterate through it and return the key with most values.

I was trying this:

```
def most_values(a):
    return max(a, key=a.get)
```

Which isn't bad though it's going to return whatever key it checks first. Next I tried:

```
def most_values(a):
    count = 0
    high = ""
    for t in a:
        if len(a[t]) > count:
            count += 1
            high = t
    return high
```

But it does the same and will return whatever key it iterated through first. It's also not a very elegant looking solution.

What's the most *Pythonic* way of going about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with:

```
return max(a, key=a.get)
```

is that here the `key` will **return the actual list** and in Python **lists are compared lexicographically**, so **not by length** (there are things to say for both ways to compare lists, but they decided to sort lexicographically). You can however easily modify this with:

```
def most_values(a):
    return max(a, key=lambda x:len(a[x]))
```

This is probably the most *Pythonic* way since it is *declarative* (you do not have to think *how* the maximum is calculated), *elegantly*,  *readable* and has *no side effects*.

---

The problem with your second approach is that you should **set `count` to the new `len(a[t])`**, not increment it. So you can fix it like:

```
def most_values(a):
    count = -1
    high = None
    for key,val in a.items():
        if len(val) > count:
            count = len(val) # semantical error in your code
            high = key
    return high
```

Comment: _you should set count to the new len(a[t])_

This really helped me understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much for the feedback on my code!

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
sorted(dictionary.iteritems(), key=lambda x:len(x[1]), reverse=True)[0][0]
```

sorted() sorts stuff. dictionary.iteritems() is an iterator for key:value pairs in the dict. key will receive such a pair and use the 2nd item in it (the value) as the thing its comparing. reverse=True will make it sort from big to small. the first [0] will return the "biggest" key value pair and the second [0] will return the key

or go with Willem Van Onsem's idea because its much cleaner

Comment: Total overkill to sort the items if you only need the maximum item. This is only better if you need many of the results.

Comment: @Wombatz you are, of course, correct, but its 3 in the morning and its the first thing that came to mind

Comment: I accepted Willem's answer because he was so thorough in pointing out the errors in my logic and explaining some details of how python interprets what I wrote. Your answer helps a lot too because you explain what each part of your code is doing and that aids in my understanding overall. Thanks Nullman!